# Adding and querying the calendar

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to add a calendar event to the Windows Phone 7 calendar (preferably choosing the default calendar for the phone). Also querying it would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Chris, i'm sorry but their is not calendar control in the SDK at this time (as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402549(VS.92).aspx section Unsupported Controls). You gonna have to build one yourself

edit: regarding adding an event in the phone calendar from within you app, this is not possible (yet ?), as per http://fragiledevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/licking-windows-phone-7/ (part about launcher and choosers)

Comment: I need the actual calendar of the phone rather than a control

Comment: ok, my bad. But the response is the same. If that existed, it would have been available in a Launcher or a Chooser. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no API available maybe you can generate an iCal/ICS event server-side with an url and launching the web browser with this url. Maybe the WP7 will recognize the format and ask to the user if he/she wants to add it to his/her calendar ?